# How to load maven dependencies from another file?

Tags: java, maven

I would like to have a "dependencies file" to be able to load this file into different maven poms. I have two poms in my project which are similar to some degree. I want the identical configuration in a third pom to be loaded by the working poms.
Is this possible?

e.g. something like:

```
<project A>
  <dependencies>
    <file> "depend.xml" </file>
  </dependencies>
  ...

<project B>
  <dependencies>
    <file> "depend.xml" </file>
  </dependencies>
  ...
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to partition your projects into Maven modules.  I'd look into that.

Comment: how about you place the POM in Github and ask your members to pull the version and use it. So that all pulled POM's will be in same line.

Comment: I haven't described my setup not thoroughly enough.
I have only one project with two pom files. I use one pom file for deployment, the other one for packaging. Both pom files should use a common xml (or whatever format) file which declares the dependencies.
(Sorry for the misunderstanding...)

Comment: That sounds a little strange. Why do you do that?

Comment: Because I was not used to the concept of "build lifecycle".
I thought that I have to have different poms for different tasks. 
e.g. one for packaging and one for deployment. 
After I found out that I can assign the plugins execution to specific phases I'm able to get along with only one pom which eliminates my whole question.

Comment: There are still two answers for your question. Maybe one of the proposed solutions will work for other users. If not, post an answer yourself and make it the accepted answer. Consider upvoting helpful answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was not used to the concept of "build lifecycle". I thought that I have to have different poms for different tasks. e.g. one for packaging and one for deployment. After I found out that I can assign the plugins execution to specific phases I'm able to get along with only one pom which eliminates my whole question.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a parent POM file, which all your projects inherit. By specifying dependencies, versions, etc. in the parent POM file, you don't need to respecify them in each project (unless you need to override them for whatever reason).

There's more information at: https://www.smartics.eu/confluence/display/BLOG/2013/07/22/Using+Aggregate+and+Parent+POMs

Answer (score 1):

You could create a hierarchical project making A and B a module of a common parent and manage your dependencies there.

## Parent

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Parent</name>
    <modules>
        <module>A</module>
        <module>B</module>
    </modules>
    ...
    <dependencies>
        ....
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

## A

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>A</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>my.package</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent/artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
```

## Use properties

You can also introduce variables to organize your versions using this pattern.

```
...
<properties>
   <alib.version>4.7</alib.version>
<properties>
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>alib</groupId>
        <artifactId>someArtifact</artifactId>
        <version>${alib.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```